# Looking for recommendations to better troubleshoot disallowed short tag in PHP 5.3 with Apache 2

Tags: php, apache, debugging, php-5.3

I'm upgrading a huge codebase for thousands of web pages to PHP 5.3 from an earlier version.  We've dropped the use of short tags (<%, <\?=, etc...) and have them disabled in the php.ini and have made reasonable effort to find any in the code and replace them.

However,  When someone creates something with or short tag or some legacy code still has one we missed, Apache returns a blank document with a 200 status.   The problem is, PHP doesn't throw an error (obviously since it's not parsing them) and Apache doesn't seem to log it is an error either.  This creates a problem for detecting these without visually inspecting all pages (a simple crawler is happy with the 200 the url returns).

Does anyone know of any way to get Apache or PHP to throw an error when it hits a short tag as a site is being crawled?

Comment: why don't you just do a mass (+ careful) find + replace?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: I was about to suggest the same thing, but that won't guard against users writing new php code with shorttags.

Comment: We did, however "be careful and find 100% of the instances" does not answer the question of ways to detect. Also, it will not detect someone adding one in tomorrow.  We'd have to add a daily check or something.

Comment: So it has to throw some error when it's run, and it can't be a check that's run as part of a test suite or source control check-in script?

Comment: @Ray well then you need to educate your developers to not use them or turn short tags on!

Comment: @Wiseguy ideally I'd like an error thrown in some log.  We don't have any automated integration test suites to check committed code at this point.  If it is impossible for PHP or Apache to raise a flag we may need to look into something like this.

Comment: As you said, PHP would simply not recognize it as code, and I don't see how Apache would do anything but happily serve files. If you are using source control, you could write a hook script that searches the new file(s) and rejects the commit if necessary. (I know you can with CVS and SVN; I haven't used others but I assume it's possible.)

Comment: @Wiseguy Thanks, if there aren't any ways to do what I'm asking I'll probably go that route (SVN hook) so you should make your comment an answer so you can get some credit.  Currently,  I use a hosted SVN so I'm not sure what ability I have to trigger scripts via hooks unless they run client-side...

Comment: i v found this //
The issue if this is parsed as a PHP document and short tags are enabled, is that the PHP interpreter will see the <? part of the <?xml tag and think that part is PHP, resulting in this error:
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ... on line ..< // verify you ERROR display config

Comment: Are you sure you want to be removing all short tags? They are always on in PHP 5.4, and you cannot disable them.

Comment: @CoryCarson That's only the echo short tag `<?= ?>`. "Regular" short tags `<? ?>` still depend on the `short_open_tag` setting in 5.4.

Comment: @CoryCarson at the moment we're going for consistency.  Realistically, 5.3 addresses the majority of problems we had and don't foresee an upgrade to 5.4 for a long time--when we do we'll re-evaluate our short tag policy choice.

Comment: Users are writing code and deploying it without testing it somewhere first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really find a way to have PHP or Apache to issue some kind of a warning related to documents with short tags, but you could set a cron job to search all files under your server's web folder and for example send an email with the results, thus at the very least having pointed out the files with short tags on it:

**Simple Example:** <sup>cron job</sup>

```
<?php

// run grep command for '<?' that don't have an immediately p
$found = shell_exec('grep -rn "<?[^p]" *');

if ($found!='') {
  // email or any other action...
}

?>
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple way to implement the check.